# Using socket to connet gmail and send gmail, but not work

Tags: java, sockets, server, smtp, gmail

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SMTPDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
      UnknownHostException {
    String msgFile = "file.txt";
    String from = "java2s@java2s.com";
    String to = "yourEmail@yourServer.com";
    String mailHost = "yourHost";
    SMTP mail = new SMTP(mailHost);
    if (mail != null) {
      if (mail.send(new FileReader(msgFile), from, to)) {
        System.out.println("Mail sent.");
          } else {
        System.out.println("Connect to SMTP server failed!");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }

  static class SMTP {
    private final static int SMTP_PORT = 25;

    InetAddress mailHost;

    InetAddress localhost;

    BufferedReader in;

    PrintWriter out;

    public SMTP(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
      mailHost = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      System.out.println("mailhost = " + mailHost);
      System.out.println("localhost= " + localhost);
      System.out.println("SMTP constructor done\n");
    }

    public boolean send(FileReader msgFileReader, String from, String to)
        throws IOException {
      Socket smtpPipe;
      InputStream inn;
      OutputStream outt;
      BufferedReader msg;
      msg = new BufferedReader(msgFileReader);
      smtpPipe = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
      if (smtpPipe == null) {
        return false;
      }
      inn = smtpPipe.getInputStream();
      outt = smtpPipe.getOutputStream();
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
      out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outt), true);
      if (inn == null || outt == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open streams to socket.");
        return false;
      }
      String initialID = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(initialID);
      System.out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
      out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
      String welcome = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(welcome);
      System.out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
      out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
      String senderOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(senderOK);
      System.out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
      out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
      String recipientOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(recipientOK);
      System.out.println("DATA");
      out.println("DATA");
      String line;
      while ((line = msg.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(line);
      }
      System.out.println(".");
      out.println(".");
      String acceptedOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(acceptedOK);
      System.out.println("QUIT");
      out.println("QUIT");
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I want learn about how to make smtp server to using socket. 
I find this example code on [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/SendingMailUsingSockets.htm).

When I write this code in Eclipse and compile but socekt smtpPipe is error.
Eclipse error message:

> Resource leak : 'smtpPipe is never closed'.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse error message : Resource leak : 'smtpPipe is never closed'

It says you are not closing the resource `smtpPipe`.  The recommended practice is to close the resource when it is no longer needed. You can achieve this by calling `smtpPipe.close()` method. 
One way of doing is to wrap your code around `try` and `finally` block. Read more about finally block [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).

Example:

```
try {
    ....
    smtpPipe = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
    ....

} finally {
   if (smtpPipe != null)
      smtpPipe.close();
}
```

Also, use the similar approach for other resources like `InputStream` and `OutputStream`